# How to a replaceAll with respect to nested tags and recognizing nested status?

Tags: java, regex, nested

I have this text:

```
  ${{stuff${{more stuff}}}}
```

I want this:

```
  data(stuff+data(more stuff))
```

Not this:

```
  data(stuffdata(more stuff))
```

My code:

```
int flags = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL;

Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{\\{(?<DATA>.*?)\\}\\}", flags);
Matcher dataMatcher = dataPattern.matcher("");


String raw = "${{stuff${{more stuff}}}}";
dataMatcher.reset(raw);

String result =  dataMatcher.replaceAll("data($1)");
```

So ... how to recognize the nested status and add the plus sign??

Comment: What if it's nested 3 levels deep? What about 6 levels? Regex is not a recursive parsing language and is unsuited to the general case of this problem.  You will have to write a real (simple) parser for this grammar.

Comment: I suggest you do replacing twice.one for "data" and one for "+data".

Comment: Otherwise, replace all with `+data`, and remove the first `+` char ;)

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to my initial comment (which still applies to the general case), I believe your grammar is actually simple enough that the problem can be solved with simple substitution:

```
${{     -->     +data(
}}      -->     )
```

Then, after you have built up the final string, *discard the first character* (i.e. `finalResult.substring(1)`.

Comment: Good one! Why use power tools when a hammer and nail will work :)